# Replacing image and class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using code to replace an image and add/remove classes with jquery when something is clicked. When you click the first time it works fine, but when you click the second time it does the same thing as the first jquery click command even though the click commands are called based on the classes which are added and removed.
In my example just find where the cursor turns into a pointer then click, its towards the bottom middle, when you click the button will move to above the cursor, when you click that it will fadeout and in but the same image will appear.

Please help

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/laqopuceqe/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
//on arrow up click
//fade page out
//replace with open nav

$('.arrow_up').bind('click',function() {
    $('.bg').fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bg').attr('src', 'other_files/images/bg_open_nav.png');
    }, 500);
    $('.bg').fadeIn(500);
    $('.arrow').removeClass('arrow_up').addClass('arrow_down');
});

//on arrow down click
//fade page out
//replace with closed nav

$('.arrow_down').bind('click',function() {
    $('.bg').fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bg').attr('src', 'other_files/images/bg.png');
    }, 500);
    $('.bg').fadeIn(500);
    $('.arrow').removeClass('arrow_down').addClass('arrow_up');
});
```

Comment: your demo is not working properly, you dont even have the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JS has already compiled the moment the DOM has loaded. As such, $('.arrow_up') is already defined and $('.arrow_down') isn't. The button element has been initialized as $('.arrow_up') and only the events bound to that are executing.

Why don't you create a separate button for arrow_down and use CSS to handle whether it is displayed or not. Should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't over complicate things. Use a different div for arrow down.

Here is a js fiddle for you to mess around with. Yours isn't working at all.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdyLc4om/

```
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="arrow_up arrow">UP</div>
        <div class="arrow_down arrow">DOWN</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://vk.com/images/gifts/256/70.jpg" class="bg" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
//on arrow up click
//fade page out
//replace with open nav

$('.arrow_up').click(function() {
    $('.bg').fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bg').attr('src', 'http://vk.com/images/gifts/256/78.jpg');
    }, 500);
    $('.bg').fadeIn(500);
    //$('.arrow').removeClass('arrow_up').addClass('arrow_down');
});

//on arrow down click
//fade page out
//replace with closed nav

$('.arrow_down').click(function() {
    $('.bg').fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bg').attr('src', 'http://vk.com/images/gifts/256/70.jpg');
    }, 500);
    $('.bg').fadeIn(500);
    //$('.arrow').removeClass('arrow_down').addClass('arrow_up');
});
```